# locking views in Xcode storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

coming from a design background myself, I like to use the storyboard as much as I can before I jump into code. That being said, I was wondering if there is a feature in Xcode that enables locking some views while adjusting other views.

Let me explain by an example.. the currently selected view is a tiny 1x60px image.. that is on top of several other images.. unfortuantely Xcode doesn't allow you to zoom in more than this level (that would have solved it). I was wondering if I can lock the other images (ie SliderContainer, blackcab_comb, funryde_com, train_comp so that they're not affected by what I do with the view.. what's happening right now is that when I try to drag the small view around, I keep on dragging the views behind it.

the way I currently deal with this is just simply updating the x,y values of the view until I get it right.. There must be a better way.

[image]

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You really shouldn't drag views around. For one, because of what you just said. Another reason being, if you're working with auto layout, you add constraints after an hour of work, then you decide do drag something, instead of changing it's X/Y value, it will mess up all the constraints.

To answer your question, I don't think there is such a feature.

Comment: i usually add my constraints after i've done all my dragging.. frankly there are many other `illustrator` uses that can really help w/ storyboard.. for example grouping of objects.. supposed i wanted to treat the bus, car and faces as one unit and center all three of those within the containing view.. anyways..